# What does "Can't create transaction: internal error: Known ring does not include the spent output..." mean?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation, ringdb

When sending a transaction from the 0.12.0.0 GUI, I get an error:

`Can't reate transaction: internal error: Known ring does not include the spent output [number]`. Replace `[number]` with a specific number.

What can I do to enable the sending of the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an excellent answer, but for now, you can get around this by deleting the `.shared-ringdb` folder.

For Windows, this located in `C:\ProgramData\.shared-ringdb`

For Mac OS X and Linux, this is located in `~/.shared-ringdb`

Note that `~` is typically short for `home/<user-name>`

Restart the GUI, and you should be able to send a transaction.

Comment: Will it be fixed in 0.12.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in early 0.12.0.0 versions which would cause this if the shared ring database failed to initialize. In current code, this is fixed. Since there are other major bugs (mainly a wallet side reporting bug), noone should use 0.12.0.0 anymore, and updating will solve this.

0.12.4.0 will be released within the week, and is the recommended version if you don't have to wait for builds. In the meantime, 0.12.3.0 is out.